# Uniform pseudo-random number generator between two numbers on GPU

Tags: random, numbers, generator, gpu

Just need a fast way to generate pseudo-random numbers between -1 and 1 on the GPU.

I've been looking at the xorshift random number generators, but I can't figure out how to constrain them between two numbers.

Comment: NVIDIA provide a dedicated random number generation library with their CUDA development toolkit, if that is any good to you.

Comment: @talonmies is right - just use cuRAND, and look at their curandGenerateUniform() call.  That gives you uniform numbers in [0,1); then just multiply by 2 and subtract 1 to get a set of numbers distributed between -1 and 1.